# Why does this C++ template code compile with a type conflict error?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

We have written a `RefCounted` object in our code base as follows; we have a type reference cycle, so we forward define the `MyCountedObject`

Can anybody explain why there is type conflict, and how to implement this type cycle reference?

Code snippet:

```
// util.cpp
namespace util {
    template <typename T, typename DeletorT> 
    class RefCounted: public T {
    };

    template <typename T> 
    class Deletor {
    };  
}
namespace ns {
    class Object {
    };

    class CX {
        class MyCountedObject;
        typedef util::RefCounted<Object, util::Deletor<MyCountedObject> > MyCountedObject;
    };
}
```

but compiling raises the following error:

```
example.cpp:16:69: error: typedef redefinition with different types ('util::RefCounted<Object,
      util::Deletor<MyCountedObject> >' vs 'ns::CX::MyCountedObject')
                typedef util::RefCounted<Object, util::Deletor<MyCountedObject> > MyCountedObject;
                                                                                  ^
example.cpp:15:9: note: previous definition is here
                class MyCountedObject;
                      ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: You can't use the same name for a class and a typedef.

Comment: First `class MyCountedObject;` followed directly by `typedef ... MyCountedObject;`. Of *course* it would be an error as you declare the same symbol (`MyCountedObject`) twice using different types.

Comment: You can't forward-declare a typedef.